# How to watch sass and javascript at the same time in gulp 4

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to convert my sass to compressed-css and javascript to uglified-js. And `watch` both scss and js changes

my code is working but when I tried saving a js file, it goes into a unstoppable loop.

Here is my code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');    
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('sass', function(done){

    gulp.src('public/sass/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'})) // Using gulp-sass
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'))

      done();
  });

gulp.task('scripts', function(done){

    gulp.src('public/javascripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascripts'))

        done();
});


  gulp.task('watch', function(){
        //I made .scss and .js into an array so they will both be watched
    gulp.watch(['public/sass/**/*.scss', 'public/javascripts/**/*.js' ], gulp.series('sass', 'scripts', function(done) {


        done();
      }))
  })
```

Now when I run `gulp watch` it is working but then when I save a js file, I goes into a saving loop, It's saves and saves and saves nonstop.

I have made scss work with this code

```
 gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('public/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass', 'scripts', function(done) {


        done();
      }))
  })
```

But I have no idea how I can make .js files be watched.

I searched google for possible answer but only find the older version solution. Is there a way I can do this with gulp4?

- I also tried `gulp.parallel` but it still looped

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
        //I made .scss and .js into an array so they will both be watched
    gulp.watch(['public/sass/**/*.scss', 'public/javascripts/**/*.js' ], gulp.series('sass', 'scripts', function(done) {

    done();
    }))
})
```

should be

```
gulp.task('watch', function(done){

    // added done above too

    gulp.watch('public/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass') )
    gulp.watch('public/javascripts/**/*.js', gulp.series('scripts') )
    done();
})
```

Your code triggers **both** `'sass'` and `'scripts'` tasks when **either** a scss or js file is modified, which is wasteful (for example, the `'sass'` task will start when a js file is altered but not actually do anything with that js file but will needlessly run the sass re-compilation although no scss file changed).

Comment: Thank you for this, I am new to gulp and all the tutorials I saw is extremely difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing this:

```
 gulp.task('watch', function(){
          //I added the src folder instead of the glob **(two asterisk)
          gulp.watch(['public/sass/**/*.scss', 'public/javascripts/src/*.js'], gulp.series('sass', 'scripts', function(done) {


    done();
  }))
```

})

I don't know why this happened but it's working now